# Is it ever worth writing a paper on evaluating one expression?

Tags: publishing

I'm not entirely sure how else to word this, but say I've solved a sum like:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \operatorname{arctanh}(n^{-3})$$ or an integral such as $$\int_1^\infty x^{-x} \,dx$$

Would things like this ever be worth noting or submitting?

Comment: Perhaps - if it were new and interesting or particularly short and clever. Your question is too hypothetical. If you've actually done something along these lines, show it to one of your instructors, or ask here for proof-verification.

Comment: That's fair. I keep a notebook of integrals and sums I've solved that I can't quite find elsewhere. I just don't know if things like that are relevant. I mean, obviously there are ones with a bit of larger signifgance, like perhaps had someone solved $\zeta(3)$ for example.

Comment: The _Monthly_ of the Mathematical Association of America publishes short notes that sometimes have things like this. So does _Mathematics Magazine_ (less prestigous). There's the arXiv, where they might be notices. If you've several that are related by  some thread you could write them up together. Do show them to someone at your school.(+1 for keeping a notebook.)